# IE Print font size smaller

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing

I am printing my page from IE using javascript print function. The text is way smaller than what it should be.

```
                    function BtnPrintClick() {

                    var printHTML = $('#divPrint').html();

                    window.innerHTML = "";
                    window.innerHTML = printHTML;
                    window.print();
```

This is my script. Why does it not pick up the font size of the web page? The font is not being resized in any @media print styling. I am using IE9.

Comment: can you add css for #divPrint

Answer (score 2):

> When you print a webpage, Internet Explorer shrinks the content of the
>   webpage to fit the width of your paper. If the webpage is wide,
>   reducing the text size to fit the page can cause the text to be
>   unreadably small

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/printing-webpages-in-internet-explorer-9-frequently-asked-questions

The user solutions proposed by microsoft are:

- Change print orientation to landscape.
- Select portions of the webpage and print them separately. See the question "How do I print specific parts of a webpage?" later in this topic for more information.
- Click the Tools button Tools button, point to Print, and then click Print preview. From the Change Print Size menu, choose Custom. Specify how large you would like the webpage to be printed by setting a percentage in the Custom Size text box. This will enlarge the printed size of the entire webpage, but it might result in some of the webpage being cut off on the printed document.

As a developper, you may look at @media to see if it overwrite the print rules of IE9.

Comment: Since the original question lists the JavaScript snippet the site runs when the user wants to print, it is safe to say that the request comes from the developer. The majority of your answer lists user workarounds. You could substantially improve your answer, in my opinion, by giving an example @media. Of course the original doesn't contain much HTML/CSS/etc. for us to work with...

Comment: @Jerome, I agree, however question is "Why does it not pick up the font size of the web page?", and the answer is correct. Much more details would be appreciated, thought.

Answer (score 0):

Check the percentage size of the impression while printing ... it might be a stupid thing. But I've already faced something similar.