# While printing the page using Window.print() the page is printed with small font size in IE11 but its prints well in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button Which prints the Page on click of a button which triggers onclick(); javascript function. the code goes like this.

```
<html>
<input type="submit" value="Print" onclick="printInfo()">
</html>
```

Script is placed in `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printInfo()
{
    window.print();
}
</script>
```

when we click on the button in Chrome and Mozilla the page is printed normally but in IE the font decreases and is set to half of the page.

Please help me on how to maintain consistent in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Maybe it's default browser css?

Comment: if you are using windows look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715586/ie-print-font-size-smaller

Comment: Not sure Justin. but one observation is like, when I print the page using CTRL+P in both the browsers the font size is similar. Issue comes when I try to print using the print button with window.print();

Comment: @Arun Yes I'm using windows and I have seen the post you mentioned. It says when the page is wide then it shrinks which leads to decrease in font size but it my case the page is not wide and would fit enough to the A4 sheet. but it shrinks and prints the page to half of the A4 page. So that post didn't help me much. Thank you.